# Firebase Query using array-contains and a range filter JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, indexing

I am trying to query documents that have a specific genre and user rating.

In the document, genres is an array[] and userRating is a number out of 5.

Here's my query:

```
q = query(
            ColRef,
            where("genres", "array-contains", "Comedy"),
            where("userRating", ">=", 3)   
          );
```

I get this error when it's run

```
FirebaseError: [code=failed-precondition]
```

Firebase Documentation says

> You can perform range (<, <=, >, >=) or not equals (!=) comparisons only on a single field, and you can include at most one array-contains or array-contains-any clause in a compound query:

Am using one array-contains and one not equals or am I not understanding what they meant is array-contains also considered a range filter?

Comment: This query is supported but you'll need to create a composite index in [Firestore](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/fire-template-24/firestore/indexes). [`genres - Arrays, userRating - Ascending`]

Comment: @Dharmaraj It didn't give me a link to create one but I created one anyways with the first field [genres => Arrays] and [userRating => Descending] still gave me the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned earlier, you need a composite index to support this query:

> `[genres - Arrays, userRating - Ascending]`

By default, the query will order results in *ascending order* based on value of `userRating`. But your index mode was `Descending` for `userRating` and hence the first index did not work.

That index would have supported your query if you had specified `orderBy('userRating', 'desc')` which orders the results in *descending order*.

You can read more about this in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#queries_supported_by_composite_indexes).